How should I handle a consistent academic misconduct by a certain group of researchers
I recently encountered an incident in our research field where a group of researcher falsely claimed credit for our work in their publications. They have been consistently publishing papers containing these false claims, even though they did not actually achieve the results they've claimed. What's more concerning is that they've gone to the extent of distorting facts to make it seem like the state of the art is worse than it actually is, misleading readers in the process.
As a reviewer for some of their subsequent papers, I found it unethical to allow such false or misleading information to be published. I provided evidence of the plagiarism and asked the editors not to include this misinformation. However, to my surprise, multiple editors supported the authors' actions, citing it as an issue with prior works that needed resolution before anything could be done.
The editors offered me several options, including directly confronting the authors, but given their awareness of the situation and their persistence in this behavior, I doubt this would be effective. Reporting to the Editor-in-Chief was another option, but colleagues warned me that given the support from multiple editors, addressing the misconduct in the original paper might be challenging.
Now, I'm faced with a new review assignment from an author who has historically supported this misconduct, and they continue to propagate these false claims. I'm torn between reporting the issue in this review, which feels morally imperative to prevent further dissemination of misinformation, and fearing potential retaliation, which has already occurred to some extent.
I would greatly appreciate any advice or feedback on how to proceed. Thank you in advance for your input.

What is your current role/position?

@BryanKrause I'm an assistant professor, which is why I'm very concerned about the consequences of this issue.

There seems to be 2 issues - plagiarism (bad) and misrepresenting the state of the art (which I think is more widespread) in fields. I'm a little surprised that editors wouldn't accept clear evidence of plagiarism. Perhaps you could describe a bit more on how grave it was?

‘false claims, even though they did not actually achieve the results’ and ‘distorting facts to make it seem like the state of the art is worse than it actually is.’ Is this a science-related area where one might expect claims to be backed up and facts to be cited?

Thanks @Someperson for your comment. I share your feeling regarding the gravity of the 2nd issue, which also suggests an intentionality behind the misconduct. Here are some context on the series of events:
In essence, our research line involves deriving some mathematical bounds that have engineering implications. There exists a seminal work, let's refer to it as result “A”, which the authors in question attempted to build upon, resulting in an improved but suboptimal result denoted as “B”. Independently, we completely solved these questions, providing a bound superior to both “A” and “B”.

@Someperson(part 2)
Following the publication of our work, the authors persistently attempted to lay claim to our findings. Initially, they falsely asserted that “A” and “B” remained the best, ignoring our solution. Despite our repeated interventions through the peer review process, they continued this behavior in their new submissions. Eventually, I became so frustrated that I asked them to stop in a review. In response, I received an aggressive reply accusing me of judging their intentions, falsely claiming they had never done this, and stating that my actions were quite grave.

@Someperson(part3) The author's tone was so convincing that I began to doubt myself. I decided to revisit their earlier paper to see if there was anything I could appreciate. To my surprise, I discovered that the journal version of their work, which they cited repeatedly but was posted years after our work, claimed that the entirety of my work was also discovered by them. When I examined their proof, I saw that they did not even bother to copy my proof but simply claimed it was trivial. This led me to report the plagiarism misconduct in my previous review assignments.

@Someperson(part4)
I cannot precisely judge why the editors chose not to address the non-plagiarism part of the issues, but one of the editors mentioned that he had communicated with the authors and decided not to include me as a reviewer for their future revisions.

@Aruralreader These results are in the field of mathematics which means everything I said can be concretely verified. But unfortunately that 1. it is difficult nowadays to convince an editor that is non-expert in our field to spend time read into details. 2. even if they read and are convinced of the authors' misconduct they refused to fix them.

I would go with this to my line manager/head of department or similar. They should know the particulars of this better than we here and be able to provide some advise.
Also, it would be helpful if you could summarise the situation more succintly/concisely than in a number of comments. (TLDR)

Contact the authors first, then consider complaining to their university
If you wish to take action on suspected research misconduct, a good first step is to contact the authors whose actions concern you and clearly (and politely) set out your concerns.  This will give them an opportunity to provide an explanation of their conduct, give supplementary information, or take corrective action.  If you are unsatisfied with their response, you can lodge a complaint with the university/universities that employ these academics.  Every reputable university has a research code of conduct and related rules that bind their academics and they are able to receive and act on complaints of research misconduct.  They typically also have rules against retaliation against a complainant.
You say in your question that there is "consistent academic misconduct" here, but actually, there is not even a single finding that academic misconduct has occurred.  If you wish to change this, you will need to make a formal complaint to the relevant universities and have the matter assessed.  In the event that the university finds that academic misconduct has occurred, they can impose sanctions on the employee and/or take action in their own right (i.e., as an institution) to correct incorrect information in publications, etc.  Academic journals are also far more likely to take corrective action themselves if a complaint is backed by an institutional finding of misconduct and recommendations from a university.

Write a review article and set the story straight. You can present your research, showing a clear progress timeline, and, with some diplomacy, contrast this to the attempts to distort the facts.

I have some sad news for you - as long as you can't convince your own scientific community of the availability and correctness of your superior solution the authors aren't even wrong: the state of the art is indeed still "A" and "B". It's not enough to publish your own results somewhere and be personally convinced of their correctness - your peers need to know about your results and, crucially, they need to agree. Recognition is given by your peers, not claimed by you.
It feels to me you are spending your time and energy on the wrong problem (getting competing authors to agree with you, who also happen to be the people with the least incentives to do so), when you should be writing follow-up papers that demonstrate the value and correctness of your results, and giving presentations about your work. I would also suggest thinking about why your results currently get ignored (and it's most likely not because you are not sufficiently famous, if that's what you are thinking):

Is the proof (too) difficult to understand?
Are the people who need your new bounds most not aware of them?
Did you publish in a venue that your target audience would not be reading?
And, of course, is your proof even correct, or are there limitations that others see but you do not?

And, if nothing helps, I strongly suggest letting it go. Getting "not-really-but-kind-of" scooped by a different group that published their results later but was more successful in dissemination happens. Sometimes history corrects this eventually, and sometimes it never does (especially when things are often not as black-or-white as they seem when you are one of the involved people). It certainly sucks when you had the right answer first but everybody applauds the genius of somebody else, but throwing around accusations of "plagiarism" mostly makes you seem like a quack.

I think you set the facts straight in the literature. It sounds like you have a standard A, their method B, and your method C. You write a paper that says something like, we are interested in the problem of improving A. We test method B and find that, in contrast to previous literature, B only slightly improves A. We then propose and test method C, which fulfills the original goal of improving A.

Also I am confused by the story, I think. Did they actually steal your work, as in copy it? Or are they publishing on the same problem as you? You said, “independently” which implies the latter. Then you said they ignored your work, which is something that is regrettable but happens and can be solved in reviews (but is not plagiarism).
